# Wix 3.9 installer - 'cs' file Vs. 'wxs' file

Tags: c#, wix, wixsharp

I am searching the web but can't find any good documentation regarding this:
what definitions should be part of the 'cs' file and what should be part of the 'wxs' file ?

I am editing an existing (and working) installer project, which is implemented only in the 'cs' file.
I am trying to implement a Major Upgrade so as to first remove any older version installed.
But since i haven't found any option to do this via the 'cs' file, i understood i first need to implement the installer in the 'wxs' file. In that case, what will be with the 'cs' file? Should i put the code there in a comment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using WixSharp and not Wix directly, you should edit CS file.

https://wixsharp.codeplex.com/

You can refer to it's manual. According to it, to implement major upgrade, you should add something like this:

```
    project.MajorUpgradeStrategy = MajorUpgradeStrategy.Default;
    project.MajorUpgradeStrategy.RemoveExistingProductAfter = Step.InstallInitialize;
```

Comment: (yeah.. i know that a .cs file is C#)  I do have a "using WixSharp" in the .cs file. After building the project, an .exe file is created - running it will create a .msi file.

Comment: Ah, you are using WixSharp! That's a third-party tool to build WIX installer, not WIX itself. I.e. you create your installer in C#, then it's "compiled" by the tool to WXS and then one more time from WIX to MSI

Comment: Edited the answer - check the WixSharp Samples, there already exists one named "MajorUpgrade"

Comment: I see now. Thank you very much, @Nikolay